# Playing video on videoview that is floating on android native screen and both have touch listeners capabilities

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-videoview, android-windowmanager, android-popupwindow

looked a lot for a similar question without any luck...

i'm trying to find the right method of playing a video(half screen window that can also be full screen when needed) with media controller. The video is supposed to float on top of the native controls ,and both the video and native controls can receive touch events(both clickable. Like Facebook messenger icon).

For now what I am doing: I start an activity that is transparent and I play the video inside a `VideoView` and I set its layout params and the activity's layout params to take half of the screen. The other half is the native screen. I am  setting the window to:

`this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |     WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY)`

What this does is that I can see the video playing on the `VideoView` **but I can't touch and use its media controller (play, pause, etc.)** , but I **can** see the native screen which I can touch !

I tried different flags which enable the media controller but then the `VideoView` consume the touch events completely. This means now **I can't touch the half that is the native screen behind it**.

[VideoView on Top Of Native Screen - Both can handle touch events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZej8.jpg)
i thought maybe using Dialogs or Popup window but couldn't find something that says Dialog can receive touch events while native screen can also receive touch events .

the video should always be on top .
Thanks in Advance ! :)